# Возврат из функции и её вызов в С++

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели

Имею 2 функции (различий меж ними нет, практически)
Правильно ли я выполняю из них возврат? И как правильно их нужно вызывать в `main` (между массивами, возвращаемых обеими функциями, нужно будет провести математические операции)?

```
int summa(int x[], int y[], int nRow)
{
        int *sum = new int[nRow];
        for (int i=0; i<nRow; i++)
                sum[i]=x[i]+y[i];
        for (int i=0; i<nRow; i++)
                return sum[i];
}

int dobutok(int x[], int y[], int nRow)
{
        int *dob = new int[nRow];
        for (int i=0; i<nRow; i++)
                dob[i]=x[i]*y[i];
        for (int i=0; i<nRow; i++)
                return dob[i];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите вернуть в первом случае `sum[0]`, а во втором - `dob[0]`, то правильно.

После выполнения `return` функция прекращает работу - так что из всего цикла `return` будет выполнено только на первой итерации.

Но если вы хотите вернуть выделенную для нового массива память - то объявляйте функцию как возвращающую `int*`, и просто возвращайте `return sum`.

Потом не забудьте освободить выделенную память.

```
int * summa(int x[], int y[], int nRow)
{
        int *sum = new int[nRow];
        for (int i=0; i<nRow; i++)
                sum[i]=x[i]+y[i];
        return sum;
}


int main()
{
    int x[] = { 1, 2, 3};
    int y[] = { 4, 5, 6};
    int * s = summa(x,y,3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) cout << s[i] << endl;
    delete[] s;
}
```

Примерно так.

Но куда лучше использовать, например, `vector` - слишком велика вероятность ошибиться и забыть удалить возвращаемый массив или перепутать, какой у него размер...

Answer (score 1):

Так как вам уже ответили, я лишь добавлю, что проще и лучше работать в таких случаях с std::valarray. Он позволит обойтись без функции и лишных забот.

```
int x[] = { 1, 2, 3};
int y[] = { 4, 5, 6};
std::valarray<int> vx(x, 3), vy(y, 3), result = vx + vy;
for (int i : result)
    cout << i << endl;
```

Comment: По условию задачи: Произведение и Сумму пары (х[i] и y[i]) через ф-ю, а разность меж ними - уже в main =) Так что так сложилось.